# putExtra sting convert to variable

Tags: android

Sorry for the silly question but im stucked

I want to send a large amount of data to other `Activity` through `putExtra`.

Is there any way to convert the "string" in `putExtra("string", data )` to a variable given that it's stupid to write 100 different strings;

Answer (score 1):

The putExtra method stores the data as a key/value pair. The string is like an index to the data it is not really a form of data in itself. When you want to retrieve your data you give the string and the system then finds the string in its indexing system and pulls out your data. Think about a book. If you want to find out about a particular subject (i.e. read some data) it would be time consuming to read the whole book to find out what you need. So instead you just check the index and you are able to go straight to the section you want and get the data you need.

Put simply the answer is NO. You must use a string and that string value must stay constant so that you can retrieve your data.

Comment: so if i want to send the LatLng of 200 different cities to another activity, should i use as string the name of every particular city;

Comment: If I wanted to do that I would probably use a different and more appropriate tool to be honest. The putExtra method is not really designed to do that. Why don't you use Androids built in SQLite database? Then both activities can access and edit the information without having to send anything!

Answer (score 0):

The string is simply the name that the data will be referred to as.  If you want to pass 100s of strings then that's pretty easy, you just have to make data be a structure that contains your strings:

```
String[] data = new String[200];
... fill in the strings ...

putExtra("multipleStrings", data);
```

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear. I receive Lat Lng from server and want to send them to other activity. I have in mind a form like  putExtra("city(1)", LatLng); putExtra("city(2)", LatLng); and so on..